# Sales order history : remove tab

Tags: magento2, xml, delete

In xml, how can I remove tab of order in `sales/order/history`? Can't find the `referenceBlock`

I just need to remove this tab, not the link. To be precise, I'm using an API that will replace this table.

Edit :

When you go to `/sales/order/history`, usualy you have a table with the history of your order. I need to remove this table

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more in your question, so that it can be easily understood and people can reply.

Comment: See updated answer, can't be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Just add this in sales_order_history.xml

```
    <referenceBlock name="sales.order.history" remove="true" />
```